# Unable to remove activity from stack,

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, service

I am starting an activity from service. ,

In this i set **two flags** one is

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` 
because i am  running activity from service.its new

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` is set to new activity is not kept in the history stack.  As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished.

**Here is the code which i call from service to open activity**

```
 public static void open(Context context){

        Intent intent=new Intent(context,PopupActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        context.startActivity(intent);    
    }
```

and i have cross button in my activity to destroy activity  , when i press cross button activity should remove from stack,but it remain in stack and when press home button to view it, activity recreated  in stack.for example "oncreate"  is again called

here is my code.

```
 @OnClick(R.id.flClose) void closeWindow(){

       finish();
    }
```

Here is my manifest activity code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackagename">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchUserActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TermsPolicyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UserDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DocumentViewerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />



        <activity
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:name=".PopupEndActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar" />


        <activity
            android:name=".BlockActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar" />


        <activity
            android:name=".BlockSettingsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            />


        <service
            android:name=".service.SyncDataService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you use `ButterKnife.bind(this);`?

Comment: Yes, it’s there .

Comment: When debugging, does the program execute `filish();` line?

Comment: Post your manifest please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved My problem by Adding flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT` This flag is used to open a document into a new task rooted at the activity launched

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
```

In manifest i have **noHistory**

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Normally you would only use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT` in combination with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`.

Comment: I'm starting activity from service that's why i use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK .  Without  ntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT  flag   my activity recreated when  i press home button

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense at all. Please add your manifest to the question.

Comment: Yes, you need to set `FLAG_ACTIVITUY_NEW_TASK` when you launch an `Activity` from a `Service`. Your comment about pressing HOME creates the `Activity` again makes no sense at all.

Comment: I update the activity code ...  I don't want to keep the activity in stack

Comment: I understand you don't want the `Activity` in the stack. But the description of the behaviour makes no sense. Please post the entire manifest. There is something else strange going on here. And what do you mean that the `Activity` is recreated when you press HOME? When you press HOME, the HOME screen should be shown. Not one of your activities. That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Yes when on home button press  home  screen is shown, in my activity " onDestroy called" ,but when i press  menu button to retrieve  it, activity remain in stack, and  also oncreate is called  again  and activity is  created again old one is remain in stack on the top old activity new one created .its repeated continuously.ok am also updating all manifeist , i didn't find any thing which have effect on this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190045/discussion-between-amkhan-and-david-wasser).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `finishAffinity()` instead of `finish()`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following flags instead of setflags to open activity

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
```

And on close button call the function below

```
private void endTask() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            finishAndRemoveTask();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this behaviour by setting the **android:noHistory** attribute to "true" in the relevant  entries in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

For example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:noHistory="true" />
```